# Writing an event to a Netty ChannelGroup creates race condition

Tags: netty

I have an event I need to send to all active connections and I am using ChannelGroup.write() for this process. As the event passes through the outbound handlers a field in the event is modified with a unique value for that connection before creating the final ByteBuf. The issue I have is that the ChannelGroup.write() sends the same event to each connection and each connection's outbound handlers modifies that one field. This creates a race condition and the receivers of my event may read an event with an incorrect value in this field.

I am not sure how to solve this issue. I could write my own ChannelGroup write() method that would wait until an event is sent before the next one is sent. Or I could create multiple copies of my event and send one to each connection. Either way it appears I am writing some custom code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the statement that working with mutable data structures in a multithreaded environment is usually a bad idea. Strive to create an immutable class, and copy it with new values when you make a mutation.

With this approach:

You don't have to write your own `ChannelGroup.write()` implementation.
You can simply copy the event object, and mutate the value **in your handler** before you pass it onwards, but prefer to create a new immutable event.

If you insist on using the same event instance for all threads, you can use a ThreadLocal for the field that you're mutating. I really think this is an overkill for your use-case.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. As is with many situations such as this I have a legacy application where I am replacing the network portion with Netty and creating an immutable class puts me in territory that I do not want to go to. I will look more into your suggestions.

Comment: If you don't want to shake the world while you refactor legacy code, I think your best option is to copy the object in the handler, before you mutate it. It's a small change unless this is a class with lots of fields and no copy c'tor.